# 12V DC motor control through Arduino

Tags: arduino, dc-motor

I have a motor with three pins. Two of them are for 0V & 12V. To activate it I need to send +12 V to third pin.

In the documents they write that the third pin is used to protect the board that sends 12 V to the motor.

What parts do I need? Do I need a diode, or a resistor and transistor? If yes can you tell me the cheapest solution?

Power is 12 V - 3A.  The Arduino is connected to a PC via USB:

[image]

Motor board circuit diagram
[image]

Comment: the reference connection is not 12V-  ... it is GND or `0 V` ... otherwise there would be 24 V applied to the motor

Comment: pin 3 in the module connector is for sensing the state of the switch ... it is not for applying power

Comment: what research have you done?